# Expression for within the current daily candle

Tags: pine-script

How do I create an expression to only be true if it falls within the current daily candle, i.e since the candle opened?

```
dailyopentime = security(syminfo.prefix+":"+ syminfo.ticker, "D", time)
```

This gives me the time of each daily open but I want only the latest daily open and beyond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lastDay = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", barstate.islast, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
bgcolor(lastDay ? color.red : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
study("My Script")
raising = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open < close ? 1 : open > close ? -1 : 0)
plot(raising)
```

Comment: hi thanks but this doesn't do what I was asking, it still gives a value for historcal days, not sure how it helps... i want raising=true only if the current time is greater or equal to the current daily open time(and excluding every time before the current daily open time)